# Not able to ajust Screen Brightness in ubuntu 18.04 in Desktop

Tags: 18.04

I have installed ubuntu in 18.04 in my pc. It is not showing screen brightness. I want to decrease the screen brightness but due to no options i not able to do so?

Any one who can help me in this problem?

Comment: is it a laptop 0r Deskt0P??

Comment: it's a desktop.

Comment: the monitor you are having should have c0ntr0l 0n brightness..

Comment: i am not to control that's why i am asking?

Comment: whats your monitor/ tv.. model num plz

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem common with Nvidia cards. If you do have an Nvidia video card, you are going to need to load the driver.

First of all do a `uname -a`, it will show something like `4.15.0-142-generic`, not exactly that, but something like that in the output.

After that do `sudo apt install linux-headers-4.15.0-142 linux-headers-4.15.0-142-generic`. It's not going to be that exact version, but the numbers have to match whatever `uname -a` gave you.

Then you are going to add the graphics driver repository: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Now you can check what driver is available: `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`

It should display a list and some entry is going to say "recommended" next to it. So you can go ahead and install it. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Make sure to reboot and you should be all set. All that said, I really do hope that somebody fixes the issue that linux-headers packages are never part of any dependencies even though you can't load the video drivers correctly without them. 16.04 had a huge problem where it lost its mind every time the kernel updated. Every time there was a kernel update, before rebooting had to remember to go in and manually install the correct header set. Otherwise pain was inevitable.